# Ansible - How to combine a list as values within a nested dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have a separate list and a list of dictionaries which I am trying to combine into a single dictionary for more efficient access in playbooks:

a simple list, named 'volume_device_path':

```
ok: [node1] => {
    "volume_device_path": [
        "/dev/sanstorage/0987654321",
        "/dev/sanstorage/1234567890"
    ]
}
```

a dictionary within a list, named 'volumes':

```
ok: [node1] => {
    "volumes": [
        {
            "format_opts": null,
            "fs_type": "xfs",
            "mount_opts": "noatime",
            "mount_path": "/data/fc100",
            "storage_protocol": "fc",
            "vol_desc": "ansible volume for fc",
            "vol_name": "data100",
            "vol_perf_pol": "high",
            "vol_size": 100000,
            "vol_suffix": "data100"
        },
        {
            "format_opts": null,
            "fs_type": "ext4",
            "mount_opts": "noatime",
            "mount_path": "/data/fc111",
            "storage_protocol": "fc",
            "vol_desc": "ansible volume for fc",
            "vol_name": "data111",
            "vol_size": 100000,
            "vol_suffix": "data111"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a new dictionary named 'volumes_combined' that looks like this, combining the two earlier data structures:

```
ok: [node1] => {
    "volumes_combined": [
        {
            "volume_device_path": "/dev/sanstorage/0987654321",
            "format_opts": null,
            "fs_type": "xfs",
            "mount_opts": "noatime",
            "mount_path": "/data/fc100",
            "storage_protocol": "fc",
            "vol_desc": "ansible volume for fc",
            "vol_name": "data100",
            "vol_size": 100000,
            "vol_suffix": "data100"
        },
        {
            "volume_device_path": "/dev/sanstorage/1234567890",
            "format_opts": null,
            "fs_type": "ext4",
            "mount_opts": "noatime",
            "mount_path": "/data/fc111",
            "storage_protocol": "fc",
            "vol_desc": "ansible volume for fc",
            "vol_name": "data111",
            "vol_size": 100000,
            "vol_suffix": "data111"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to get fairly close with the below, but ran into a complication.

'volume_device_path' list values do not nest inside the dictionary like I would prefer.  How do I combine the initial list values into a nested dictionary?

```
    - name: combine volumes input file and volume_device_paths
      set_fact:
        volumes_combined: "{{ volumes_combined|default({}) | combine({ item.0: item.1 }) }}"
      loop: "{{ query('together', volume_device_path, volumes) }}"
```

debug output:

```
ok: [node1] => {
    "volumes_combined": {
        "/dev/sanstorage/0987654321": {
            "format_opts": null,
            "fs_type": "xfs",
            "mount_opts": "noatime",
            "mount_path": "/data/fc100",
            "storage_protocol": "fc",
            "vol_desc": "ansible volume for fc",
            "vol_name": "data100",
            "vol_size": 100000,
            "vol_suffix": "data100"
        },
        "/dev/sanstorage/1234567890": {
            "format_opts": null,
            "fs_type": "ext4",
            "mount_opts": "noatime",
            "mount_path": "/data/fc111",
            "storage_protocol": "fc",
            "voldesc": "ansible volume for fc",
            "volname": "data111",
            "volsize": 100000,
            "volsuffix": "data111"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**'volume_device_path' list values do not nest inside the dictionary**"*

```yaml
  volumes_combined: "{{ volumes_combined|default({})|
                        combine({ item.0: item.1 }) }}"
```

A: A couple of fixes is needed

- `default([])` ... The variable *volumes_combined* is a list.
- `+` instead of `combine` ... Add an item to the list.
- `[item.1|combine({'volume_device_path': item.0 })]` ... Combine the dictionaries

```yaml
  volumes_combined: "{{ volumes_combined|default([]) +
                        [item.1|combine({'volume_device_path': item.0 })] }}"
```

Comment: Three answers in three days.  Thank you so much for helping me out this week, you are now my favorite person on the Internet!  I really appreciate the additional comments explaining your answer in this post as well.  Have a good day!